# hover on other tag element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I try to do hover on other tag element when mouse over on a element. but its not working, it is working when both elements are in same `div` tag.

**html**

```
<div id="wrap">
<div id="wrap1">
    <div class="a" id='aa'>AAAA</div>
</div>
<div id="wrap2">
    <div class ="b" id='bb'>BBBB</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.a {
    color: red;
}

.b {
    color: orange;
}

#aa:hover ~ #bb {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

**Note:**I don't want to use `jQuery`.

Comment: It can't work since #aa is not a sibling of #bb. You could write #wrap1:hover ~ #wrap2 #bb

Comment: should I write js? wouldn't css do this?

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be done in pure CSS, you will have to write some JS.

I suggest using jQuery since it makes these kinds of manipulations very easy e.g. in your case:

```
$('#aa').hover(
    function() {
        $('#bb').css('background-color','blue')
    },
    function() {
        $('#bb').css('background-color','')
    }
)
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9nN6W/

With a little more effort same can be done in plain vanilla JS as well, but why invent the wheel.

If you want to do this in pure CSS, elements have to be accessable via CSS, for example you can target the "wrap" DIVs:

```
#wrap1:hover ~ #wrap2 {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/9nN6W/1

By popular requests: Pure JS solution

```
document.getElementById('aa').addEventListener('mouseenter', 
    function() {
        document.getElementById('bb').style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
    }
)

document.getElementById('aa').addEventListener('mouseleave', 
    function() {
        document.getElementById('bb').style.backgroundColor = '';
    }
)
```

Demo 3: http://jsfiddle.net/9nN6W/2/

Comment: I don't want to use `jQuery`, I want to use only `javascript`.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript it is then :-)

```
document.getElementById("aa").onmouseover=function(){
        document.getElementById("bb").style.backgroundColor="blue";     
    };
    document.getElementById("aa").onmouseout=function(){
        document.getElementById("bb").style.backgroundColor="";
    };
```

Comment: I don't want to use jQuery, I want to use only javascript